# Is there a pattern for a lazy-loaded getter in a Collection-backed prototype (Building a reactive ORM relationship in JavaScript/Meteor)

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-collections

I am trying to simulate a lazy-loaded array of items within a Collection-backed Meteor prototype, but with reactivity.

So, say I have a Collection of books w/ a Prototype:

```
Book = function(document) {
  this._title = document.title;
  this._author = document.author;
  // ...
};
Books.prototype = {
  get id() {
    // Read-only
    return this._id;
  },
  get title() {
    return this._title;
  },
  set title(value) {
    this._title = value;
  },
  // ...
};
Books = new Meteor.Collections('books', {
  transform: function(doc) {
    return new Book(doc);
  }
});
```

And now I want to have a Shelves collection of Shelf, but I want to lazy-load the Books:

```
Shelf = function(document) {
  this._location = document.location;
  this._floor = document.floor;
  // ...
  this._book_ids = document.book_ids;
};
Shelf.prototype = {
  get id() {
    // Read-only
    return this._id;
  },
  get location() {
    return this._location;
  },
  set location(value) {
    this._location = location;
  },
  // ...
  get book_ids() {
    // This returns an array of just the book's _ids
    return this._book_ids;
  },
  set book_ids(values) {
    this._book_ids = values;
    // Set _books to "undefined" so the next call gets lazy-loaded
    this._books = undefined;
  },
  get books() {
    if(!this._books) {
      // This is what "lazy-loads" the books
      this._books = Books.find({_id: {$in: this._book_ids}}).fetch();
    }
    return this._books;
  }
};
Shelves = new Meteor.Collections('shelves', {
  transform: function(doc) {
    return new Shelf(doc);
  }
});
```

So, now I have a Self that I can now call `Shelf.books` on and get all of the `Books`, but they are not loaded until I call it.  Furthermore, a call to set the `book_ids` will cause the data to be invalidated, so the next call to `books` yields the new set of `Books` associated with that `Shelf`.

Now how do I make this reactive such that updates to `book_ids` triggers a recall to finds the right `Books`, and doing so triggers anyone that has `Shelf.books` will now get triggered to refresh?  Or, better yet, if a `Book` is updated then everything related to that `Book` (the `Shelf.books` and anyone who called it) gets reactively updated as well?